# How to create a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

so I have some problems with my dictionaries in python. For example I have dictionary like below:

```
d1 = {123456:xyz, 892019:kjl, 102930491:{[plm,kop]}
d2= {xyz:987, kjl: 0902, plm: 019240, kop:09829}
```

And I would like to have nested dictionary that looks something like that.

```
d={123456 :{xyz:987}, 892019:{kjl:0902}, 102930491:{plm:019240,kop:09829}}
```

is this possible? I was searching for nested dictionaries but nothing works for me.

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: *"nothing works for me"* - show us what you already tried then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to loop through `d1` and assign the correct values from `d2`.

**Code:**

```
d1 = {123456:'xyz', 892019:'kjl', 102930491:['plm','kop']}
d2 = {'xyz':987, 'kjl': 902, 'plm': 19240, 'kop':9829}

result = {}
for k, v in d1.items():
    if isinstance(v, list):
        result[k] = {k: d2.get(k) for k in v}
    else:
        result[k] = {v: d2.get(v)}

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{123456: {'xyz': 987}, 892019: {'kjl': 902}, 102930491: {'plm': 19240, 'kop': 9829}}
```

The above uses [`isintance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) to check if the value is a list, so you can loop over it and assign the correct values from `d2`. It also uses [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to ensure `None` is added if a [KeyError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError) was encountered when searching for a key  in `d2`.

**One-liner:**

```
{k: {k: d2.get(k) for k in v} if isinstance(v, list) else {v: d2.get(v)} for k, v in d1.items()}
```

But this becomes messy and less maintainable.

Comment: Thank you so much :) this helped like a charm. I appreciate it with all my heart. I was messing with this for the last week.

Comment: @mfweewee Np. Glad I could help :).

Comment: Maybe you could help again, cause I see you are an expert :) Now my result dictionary needs to be merged with another dictionary. And I tried this way again, but i get an output {{new_value1: 123456: None, new_value2: 892019: None, new_value3: 102930491: None}. I lose the inner dictionary :(

Answer (score 0):

First, you hate to put brackets around your keys and values.

```
d1 = {'123456':'xyz', '892019':'kjl', '102930491':'plm'}
d2= {'xyz':'987', 'kjl':'0902', 'plm':'019240', 'kop':'09829'}
```

Then I suggest you do a for loop

```
for key, value in d1.iter():
    d1[key] = d2[value]
```

I have ignored your `{[plm,kop]}` thing. But it wont be difficult to implement it if you understand this first example.